# Unable to make sense of this Windbg output while debugging a Windows Phone app

Tags: c#, debugging, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windbg

I'm debugging a crash log obtained from Windows Phone Dev Center
as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj206725%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

When I run the command `windbg -y debug;DownstreamStore -i debug -z debug\<cabname>.cab -v`,

where the `debug` folder contains

1. symbols file for my app (.pdb)
2. the app executable (image file -
   .xap), and
3. the crash log as .cab file

the folder `DownstreamStore` contains Symbols for Windows Phone 8, obtained using `.symfix+ DownstreamStore` as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552208%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The contents of this folder are:

agcore.pdb
combase.pdb
coreclr.dll
coreclr.pdb
CoreUI.pdb
crypt32.pdb
kernel32legacy.pdb
kernelbase.pdb
Microsoft.Phone.Interop.pdb
Microsoft.Phone.pdb
mscorlib.pdb
mswsock.pdb
npctrl.pdb
ntdll.pdb
pingme.txt
user32.pdb
ws2_32.pdb

I get this in the output of windbg

`Loading unloaded module list

..............

Loaded dbghelp extension DLL

Loaded ext extension DLL

Loaded exts extension DLL

Loaded uext extension DLL

Loaded ntsdexts extension DLL

This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.

The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.

(fc0.ce8): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first/second chance not available)

Unable to load image ntdll.dll, Win32 error 0n2

Loading symbols for 77390000        ntdll.dll ->   ntdll.dll

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for ntdll.dll

ntdll!NtAlpcSendWaitReceivePort+0x6:

Loading symbols for 75c40000 errorhandlingext.dll ->   errorhandlingext.dll

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for errorhandlingext.dll

*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for errorhandlingext.dll

773ef28a 4770     bx          lr {errorhandlingext+0x3eca (75c43eca)}`

I am unable to make sense of two things here:

1. What does the above error regarding ntdll.dll even mean
2. What is errorhandlingext.dll and where do I find this (or its symbols)?

PS: This is the first time I'm debugging a Windows Phone app crash log (and first time using Windbg)

Answer (score 0):

The warning re ntdll.dll means that it's not present in the dump file, and therefore the debugger can't verify its timestamp. The timestamp is not present in the information collected in the minidump you get from the store. However, if you have the right symbols for ntdll.dll (and it seems that you do), you can disregard this warning.

The error re errorhandlingext.dll means you really don't have symbols for that one. I would try the Microsoft symbol server, in WinDbg:

`.symfix c:\localsymbolcache
.reload`